# How to calculate surface area of a curved plane?

Tags: surfaces

could anyone explain how to calculate the surface area of a curved plane?  I am trying to calculate the surface area of a "vaulted" ceiling that is 24' long, 7' wide, and the height of the curve is 4' at the mid-point so that I can figure out how much paint I need to buy.

Here is an illustration:

[image: Illustration of surface]

If it were a simple flat ceiling, I would just multiply length x width, but that's not what I have here and a google search is leaving me empty-handed.  Any ideas?

Thank you very much!
-Neal

Comment: It depends on the precise shape of the surface. Is this particular one supposed to be half a cylinder?

Comment: If you take it as an approximate cylinder then a conservative estimate is $\pi r L$. easy part $L=24$. Hard part what is $r$, you can take $r=\max\{7/2,4\}$ that is $r=4$ and have a quick answer $\pi * 4 *24$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, we can figure out the area as follows:

A rough estimate (taking the width as 8 instead of 7, which gives a half-circle) gives $\pi r l = 96 \pi \approx 300$.

$\tan \theta = \frac{4}{3.5} $, $r \sin \theta = \frac{\sqrt{4^2+(3.5)^2}}{2}$. Since $\sin \theta = \frac{4}{\sqrt{4^2+(3.5)^2}} $, we have $r = \frac{4^2+(3.5)^2}{8} = \frac{113}{32}$.

$\theta = \arctan \frac{4}{3.5} \approx 0.85917$.

Hence the length of the arc is $r (4 \theta) = (\frac{113}{32}) 4 \arctan \frac{4}{3.5} \approx 12.034$. Hence the required area is $\approx 24 \cdot 12.034 = 288.82$. This is consistent with the rough estimate.

[image]

Comment: Fascinating... It's been a long time since college for me but I remember now why I enjoyed math.  Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

use the formulae you derived in part 1 to calculate the curved surface area and the total surface area of the cylinder given below

Comment: Your answer is correct, Can you please add more details?

Answer (score -1):

Just calculate the cross-section length and multiply it with 24".
This is the simplest solution, without integration.

**In order to deal with this more precisely, we must know the exact shape of the cross-section i.e. if it's a part of a circle or not**

EDIT: I just did some thinking, and this cannot be a part of a circle obviously.
It is illogical to me that what we are looking at are actually two arcs glued together.
This is a parabola - once we find out its equation, we will find the surface - I'm working on that.

Here - the equation of parabola is $$h(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})=y$$

The length of parabola arc is $$\sqrt{(a^2+4*h)}+\frac{2a^2}{2h}sinh^{-1}(\frac{2h}{a})$$

Here, a and h are the half-width which is 3.5 and height which is 4.

When you enter the numbers, the arc length is 7.418', and the surface is $$7.418*24=178.032$$